# php $_SESSION TWIG + Mini2

Tags: php, session, frameworks, twig

I'm currently working on a new project based on Mini2 PHP framework
([here is the GitHub of the framework](https://github.com/panique/mini2)).

As you can see this framework use Twig, but when I want to log in people with a form, I send a request to the Model.php where I start a Session and set $_SESSION['user'] = 'John' for exemple.

The issue is that I have no idea how to check on other page is the Session has been created or even how to show the user name on a page.

Could you please help me ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Have you tried googling $_session or using the search option of this site?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
session_start(); // start the session to have access to the session variables

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) { // check the existance of a variable with isset()
  echo "User ".$_SESSION['user']." is logged on";
}
```